# How to compare two different OData model

Tags: c#, .net, odata, wcf-data-services

I have two different data services.

I need to compare the data from these two data services and integrate results into Database using data services.

This should be done using OData

Comment: Please provide the relevant code you've tried, a sample of the data, and the outcome.

Comment: i had refered this http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/calling-an-odata-service-from-a-net-client

Answer (score 0):

OData V4 Contains this kind of feature: [Here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-data-aggregation-ext/v4.0/cs01/odata-data-aggregation-ext-v4.0-cs01.html#_Toc378326290) is the protocol. But it is not implemented in ODL now.
On the other hand, service can implement a customer function to meet the requirement.